# Rails: Parse route information from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

How can I parse url string to hash like

```
{:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name', :id => 'id'}
```

?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. It depends on the format of the url.

Comment: I have this same question... regardless of url format. i.e. what's the inverse of url_for?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Rails 3 you can do the following:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/accounts/1"
# {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts", :id=>"1"}
```

Using ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path kept throwing ActionController::RoutingError Exception: No route matches "/accounts/1

Answer (score 12):

You may be able to use `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path`, depending on the format of the URL:

```
>> ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path("/accounts/1",:method=>:get)`
# {:action=>"show":controller=>"accounts",:id=>"1"}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this drops extra params, ex "/accounts/1?verify=true" it drops verify