# get controller and action information from url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I get information about controller and action names for any (not only current) url, if there is a route rule for this?

For example:

```
function_i_need('/pages/5')
```

returns

```
{:controller => 'page', :action => 'show', :id => 5}
```

UPD: Answer found [Rails parse url to hash(Routes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733678/rails-parse-url-to-hashroutes)

Comment: Do you mean like running rake routes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733678/rails-parse-url-to-hashroutes

Comment: @VictorMoroz, yes, it's exactly what I want

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can do this:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/pages/5"
```

Comment: Which has a bug in Rails 3.2.13 -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020843/rails-3-2-13-recognize-path-returns-routing-error-for-constraints.  Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: You can specify the http verb for these as well: `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/pages/5', method: 'POST')`