# Rails 3.2.13 recognize_path returns routing error for constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two paths in my routes, same path pointing to the different controller and action

```
match '/:id' => 'users#show', :as => 'user', :constraints => UserConstraint
match '/:id' => 'customers#show', :as => 'customer'
```

My constraint class has the following matches? method

```
def self.matches?(request)
    return User.exists?(request.path_parameters[:id])
 end
```

this works fine when i call the urls in my browser. however, this does not work for recognize_path method.

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("/trump", {:method => :get})
```

returns a routing error (no route matches) whereas works when called in browser as it is appropriately routed.

a user with :id => trump exists.

how do i get recognize_path method to return the path details?

Comment: What's the definition of UserConstraint?

Comment: UserConstraint is an advanced constraint class as explained in  [rails routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, saw other questions of people apparently running into the same issue but none of them had an answer yet

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, it's a bug in Rails, see:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8679