# Query which controller will be used for a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### Question

I'm looking for something in the rails console or similar where I can call `get_controller_for_path('/some/path/')` and it will return the corresponding controller.

#### Background

I have a rails project with a lot of routes. I'm investigating a routing problem and want to confirm that a given URL will match a specific route.

I can use `bundle exec rake routes` to view the list of routes, but that still requires my human eyes to parse the hundreds (thousands?) of routes and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: [Rails parse url to hash(Routes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733678/rails-parse-url-to-hashroutes)

That says it's `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path "/accounts/1"`

You can also use `assert_routing` in your tests. If you don't have tests, now is a very good time to add some. And you can read the source of `assert_routing`, and `assert_recognizes`, to see what they do.